# Calculating Log base 2

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Let's have the following code

```
(float)Math.Log(3.83031869)
```

The output i got is

```
1.342948
```

But when i calculated the Log2 for same number using many online calculators I got

```
 1.93746
```

any illustration please ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

[`Math.Log(num)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x80ywz41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the log of base e

[`Math.Log(num, base)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd50b6h5(v=vs.110).aspx) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

When calling the Log method with only a single argument, you get the Log base e.  If you provide the second argument of 2.0, you get the result you expect:

```
//Testing in LinqPad
void Main()
{
    Math.Log(3.83031869).Dump();
    Math.Log(3.83031869, 2.0).Dump();
}
```

Results

```
1.34294800860817
1.93746443219072
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. BTW,  I got (-infinity) Log2 og of some numbers. How could I solve this problem ?

Comment: What inputs caused that result?  According to the docs, that happens when the input is 0 and the base is greater than 1 or in the input is +infinity and the base is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 6):

As can be seen in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x80ywz41.aspx

The `Math.Log` function computes the log with base `e`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd50b6h5.aspx for what you need.

Answer (score 3):

For integer values:

```
    public static int Log2(UInt64 value) {
        int i;
        for (i = -1; value != 0; i++)
            value >>= 1;

        return (i == -1) ? 0 : i;
    }
```

Comment: Not that this will also trim the output result. For instance, Log2(3) results in 1.58496250072 but will give 1, not 2.

Comment: Yes, if you need number of bits in the number then: return (i == -1) ? 0 : (value < 1U<<i) ? i : i + 1;

Answer (score 0):

C# has a function that calculates the log in base 2 for you, look at the following code:

int number;

double logBase2 = Math.Log2(number);

If you want to round the number for 2 or 3 or whatever number after the commas, you can use the following code:

double logBase2 = Math.Round(Math.Log2(number), 2);//2 digits after the commas

Comment: Note that this method requires .NET 5+ or .net Core 3+ and does not exist in .NET Framework

Comment: Thank you so much for this note my friend, I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

This is the top DDG result for `C# log2`, so while the original question was about *floats/reals*, here's the method for *integers*:

```cs
using System.Numerics;
// ...
Console.WriteLine(BitOperations.Log2(0x2EU)); // ==> 5
// always equal to Math.Floor(Math.Log2(n)), except for 0: Math.Log2(0.0) is -Inf, but BitOperations.Log2(0U) is 0U
// related function:
Console.WriteLine(BitOperations.LeadingZeroCount(0x2EU)); // ==> 26
```

This is included in .NET Core 3.0+, but not in any version of .NET Framework or .NET Standard. When targeting those you'll need to [use a polyfill](https://github.com/udaken/Shim.System.Numerics/issues/2) or [implement it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50718255).